# Application crashes on launch due to Core Data fault

Tags: ios, core-data, exception

A tester has run into a situation in which the (iOS) app crashes on launch due to a Core Data fault that could not be fulfilled (an `NSObjectInaccessibleException` is thrown). Because the first thing the application does is populate a table view with managed objects, the application continues to crash on launch.

The question is simple. **How can I solve this problem so that the tester can at least continue using the application without loss of data?**

To provide a bit more context for this question, the application crashes when the table view cells are configured as shown below. This method is invoked from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Fetch Store
    CCDStore *store = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure Cell
    [cell.textLabel setText:[store name]]; // Exception is thrown due to Core Data fault
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[store numberOfLists]];
}
```

Because I don't have access to the device or (SQLite) database, my guess is that part of the database contains corrupt data resulting in the fault.

Answer (score 0):

When I see faults in my app, usually it happens due to releasing the `NSManagedObjectContext`. When an `NSManagedObject` is "taken" from the context, and then the context is released, the object fires a fault in order to free memory. So maybe checking if the context exists can tell you if that's the problem. If it is, be sure you retain it the correct way (if you use ARC, declare the context in the interface file of your class.

Comment: I have performed those checks, but that seems not to be the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not ideal, but adding a `@try / @catch` around lines that are problematic and handling the fault in the catch will prevent your app from crashing.